# Regex to match a digit pattern with rotations

Tags: regex

What I'd like to match is the pattern `012345678901234567890123456789` but also `345678901234567890123456789012`. Meaning, I want to match the first 30 characters of this pattern but I don't know in advance the first digit.

Is there a way to match any rotation of this pattern?

Comment: In a programming environment there are easier ways to do this than with regex.

Comment: @trincot I completely agree, regex is not the golden hammer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done using alternation, however I'm not sure how efficient this is performance-wise:

```
^(?!.*(?:0[^1]|1[^2]|2[^3]|3[^4]|4[^5]|5[^6]|6[^7]|7[^8]|8[^9]|9[^0]))\d{30}$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/UZ4FN1/1), where:

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `(?!` - Open a negative lookahead:

  - `.*` - 0+ characters other than newline.
  - `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

    - `0[^1]|1[^2]|2[^3]|3[^4]|4[^5]|5[^6]|6[^7]|7[^8]|8[^9]|9[^0]` - Basically assure that all digits are only followed by their appropriate successor using alternation.
    - `)` - Close non-capture group.
  - `)` - Close lookahead.
- `\d{30}` - 30 Digits.
- `$` - End string anchor.

Comment: Well explanation is confusing, because what you used is to assure there is not any digit which is not followed by their appropriate successor :) Very nice solution though.

Comment: What about the last digit? That should fail, as it is not followed by its successor but line end or another character?

Comment: @Jan, I assumed op is validating one at a time. I couldn't implement the appropriate solution for multiline validation, but in such a case you'd need to add the newline character to the character class.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn, did I mess something up here. Should I pay more attention explaining the alternation is what you meant?

Comment: Explanation is valid, because it explain what end goal is, so overall I think is good enough :)

Answer (score 1):

To ensure also the last digit within any group of characters and more positive (no negative lookahead but a positive one):

### edit

to accommodate any sequence of the request it is actually better to

- search for 29 digits followed by the right one
- followed by one digit preceded by the right one:

line break added for readability only!

```
(0(?=1)|1(?=2)|2(?=3)|3(?=4)|4(?=5)|5(?=6)|6(?=7)|7(?=8)|8(?=9)|9(?=0)){29}
((?<=0)1|(?<=1)2|(?<=2)3|(?<=3)4|(?<=4)5|(?<=5)6|(?<=6)7|(?<=7)8|(?<=8)9|(?<=9)0)
```

This looks quite perfect now to me :)

### first solution failed on 31 digits in I a row

```
(0(?=1|[^\d])|1(?=2|[^\d])|2(?=3|[^\d])|3(?=4|[^\d])|4(?=5|[^\d])|5(?=6|[^\d])|6(?=7|[^\d])|7(?=8|[^\d])|8(?=9|[^\d])|9(?=0|[^\d])){30}
```

this searches for 30 numbers 0 to 9 followed by their successor or not a number:

https://regex101.com/r/rTYByt/1