# Regex to match the pattern 0123456789 with unknown length

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I'd like to match the following pattern: `0123456789`

The catch is that I don't know in advance the length of the string but I do know that it starts from zero. So possible strings are:

- (empty string is valid too)
- `01234`
- `0123456789`
- `01234567890123`
- `012345678901234567890123`

How can I match this with regex only?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

The whole string from beginning to end needs to be matched

Comment: can you please tell which programming language are you using for this match check?

Comment: @Kent, I'm using Python

Comment: @JvdV, my knowledge in regex is quite limited so I've decided to consult here (actually wanted to point to your previous answer)

Comment: Thank you so much @JvdV, I'm intending to do so! Can you just give an intuitive explanation on how this regex operates? Also, can you write this as an answer please so I can approve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems all you need is a simple adaptation to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66730377/9758194) previous answer from a while back:

```
^(?!.*(?:0[^1]|1[^2]|2[^3]|3[^4]|4[^5]|5[^6]|6[^7]|7[^8]|8[^9]|9[^0])|[1-9])\d*$
```

The main difference is another alternation inside the negative lookahead ....`|[1-9]` to prevent anything other than a leading zero. Then we replace the `\d{30}` with `\d*` to match an empty string as well.

Answer (score 0):

Rodolfo's answer is great. However, there are some improvements to be made!

### Regex Pattern

All test cases passed with this pattern.

```regex
^((0(1(2(3(4(5(6(7(8(9)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)+$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KiV1Ry/1)**

Comment: Headsup that this also will allow things like '0000'.

Comment: Even patterns like '010101010120120123000' will be valid. Just be careful here =)

Answer (score -1):

^(0(1(2(3(4(5(6(7(8(9)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)+$

Test it here: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Hi Rodolfo, thanks a lot! It seems that the string "0" doesn't match. Why?

Comment: Also, is it possible to match it till the end of string? (so something like "0123456X" will fail)

Comment: @yaseco I've edited the answer. The "0 does not match" was due to a missing ? that I added. I also added ^ at the beginning and $ at the end in order to match a full string on a single line. Feel free to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: This will match strings such as `010101` or `012012012` as well. (I am not sure whether that is intented. I am just pointing it out.)

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest if you do it with an or operator.

```
(0123456789|012345678|01234567|0123456|012345|01234|0123|012|01|0)+
```

https://regex101.com/r/mRBPUN/1

Comment: my eye-parser tells me, this will match `0000000000` or  `0101010101`